# How to insert data from MS Access to SQL after checking whether the data exists or not in the database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

Hopefully, the question header is clear enough to tell that I'm trying to read an Access file and upload the data to the database but checking at first whether the data already exists or not in the database.

I receive a daily report from a third-party company in Access file. I'm trying to create a windows service that will check for the file every morning, and if the new file exist, then it'll read and upload the data to the database. I'm trying to use Entity Framework. I read the article on Navigation Property, but I'm still confused on that; I never used navigation property before. Here are my models:

```
    [Table("ClaimsTable")]
    public partial class ClaimsTable
    {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int ClaimsID { get; set; }
            public string EOPAID { get; set; }
            public string AuthID { get; set; }
            public string PAStatus { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
            public string RecordType { get; set; }
            public int RxID { get; set; }
            public int MemberID { get; set; }
            public int PrescriberID { get; set; }
            public string EditNumber { get; set; }
            public string OriginSource { get; set; }
            public string OriginMethod { get; set; }
    /*
            [ForeignKey("RxID")]
            public virtual RxTable Prescription { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("MemberID")]
            public virtual MembersTable Member { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("PrescriberID")]
            public virtual PrescribersTable Prescriber { get; set; }
    */
        }
```

...

```
    [Table("MembersTable")]
    public partial class MembersTable
    {
           [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int MemberID { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Date), Display(Name= "Date of Birth"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:mm/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
            public DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }

            public string CardholderID { get; set; }
            public string MemberFirstName { get; set; }
            public string MemberLastName { get; set; }
            //public virtual ICollection<AddressTable> Address { get; set; }
    }
```

...

```
    [Table("PrescribersTable")]
    public partial class PrescribersTable
    {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int PrescriberID { get; set; }
            public string NPI { get; set; }
            public string PrescriberFirstName { get; set; }
            public string PrescriberLastName { get; set; }
            public string PhysicianType { get; set; }
            //public ICollection<AddressTable> Address { get; set; }
        }
```

....

```
        using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strDSN))
        {
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from table", conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch(OleDbException o)
            {
                return o.Message;
            }

            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            List<ClaimsTable> Claim = new List<ClaimsTable>();
            List<PrescribersTable> PrescriberInDB = new List<PrescribersTable>();
            List<MembersTable> MembersInDB = new List<MembersTable>();

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                PrescriberInDB = context.Prescribers.ToList();
                MembersInDB = context.Members.ToList();

                //CREATE LOCAL VARIABLE
                string recordType =                             //check if the member and the prescriber exist in the database
                int prescriberID = 0;
                int prodID = 0;
                int memberID = 0;
                int drugID = 0;
                int RxID = 0;
                int claimID = 0;

                //check if the member and the prescriber exist in the object before inserted into the database. 
                //the data will be uploaded to the database in bulk 
                //int newPrescriberID = Prescriber.Where(x => x.PrescriberFirstName == reader["Prescriber First Name"] && x.PrescriberLastName == reader["Prescriber Last Name"] && x.NPI == reader["Prescribing Physician"]).Select(x => x.PrescriberID).FirstOrDefault();
                //int newMemberID = Member.Where(x => x.MemberFirstName == reader["Member First Name"] && x.MemberLastName == reader["Member Last Name"] && x.CardholderID == reader["CardhHolder"]).Select(x => x.MemberID).FirstOrDefault();

                //insert the data if it doesn't exist

                if(!PresciberExist(prescriberFirstName, prescriberLastName, npi, PrescriberInDB)) 
                {
                    var prescriber = new PrescribersTable()
                    {
                        PrescriberFirstName = prescriberFirstName,
                        PrescriberLastName = prescriberLastName,
                        NPI = npi,
                        PhysicianType = physicianType                                    
                    };

                    context.Prescribers.Add(prescriber);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    prescriberID = GetPrescriberID(prescriberFirstName, prescriberLastName, physicianType, PrescriberInDB);
                }
                if(!MemberExist(memberFirstName, memberLastName, cardholderID, MembersInDB))
                {
                    var member = new MembersTable()
                    {
                        MemberFirstName = memberFirstName,
                        MemberLastName = memberLastName,
                        CardholderID = cardholderID,
                        DateofBirth = dob
                    };

                    context.Members.Add(member);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    memberID = GetMemberID(memberFirstName, memberLastName, cardholderID, MembersInDB);
                }


        }
    }
    return "Done uploading";
}

private bool MemberExist(string memberFirstName, string memberLastName, string cardholderID, List<MembersTable> MembersInDB)
{
    return MembersInDB.Exists(x => x.MemberFirstName == memberFirstName && x.MemberLastName == memberLastName && x.CardholderID == cardholderID);
}

private bool PresciberExist(string prescriberFirstName, string prescriberLastName, string npi, List<PrescribersTable> PrescriberInDB)
{
    return PrescriberInDB.Exists(x => x.PrescriberFirstName == prescriberFirstName && x.PrescriberLastName == prescriberLastName && x.NPI == npi);
}
```

The access database contains sensitive information, so I won't be able to add those data as an example. But here's a made up data for test. The data contains claims of patients.

Now, because there are many drugs and many claims for the same patient, and many patients for a prescriber.. I broke the database as it's shown above. Needs improvement? I welcome suggestion. The reason I did this is because I don't want my database to have repeated records which will make managing really troubling. This way, I'll have unique members in memberstable, unique prescribers in prescriberstable and so on and so forth.

The challenge I'm facing is that when I read the data from the access database, I'm assuming it reads row-wise. The code should first check the database whether the member exist or not. If it does, then get the member id which is an identity column. If it doesn't, then it should insert the member's info only, and then get the memberID. Similarly, I do the same thing with the prescriber's data. Check and insert if needed. This is the long way, and this is the only way I could figure out how to do it.

I know this is not a very good programming. I'm just an analyst who unfortunately has to do a lot of programming. And I'm learning as I go. With that said, there's a lot of ways to improve this code - I just don't know any. Can you point me to the right direction? Also, an example of how to check and insert the data if it doesn't exist in the database using navigation property. Currently, the data is read and uploaded just fine, but I saw in the database that it didn't quite do what I wanted it to do. It still added a couple of already existing members. I seriously needs some help.

Comment: can you clean up the code that you posted.. is the code in red useful code or commented code .. also if you are assuming as you have put it.. I think it's fair for us to `assume` that you have not used the `debugger` to step through your own code.. this is way toooooo much code to be pasting in regards to you expecting someone to help you debug this in my opinion

Comment: @MethodMan I don't know why it showed up red. Even I was trying to figure it out. The reason I put in all the code is because I thought it is related. Also, I did use debugging. But the point is not with how to debug. It's to show that I'm not using proper method. I just need some help using Navigation Property and inserting the data after checking whether it exists or not. I'll remove some of the codes. Thank you.

Comment: put this line inside the try block `reader = command.ExecuteReader();` where you are doing this 
`OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from table", conn);`

Comment: @MethodMan, I'll try that later. Due to the earthquake in Nepal, I'm stuck outside the house inside a tent. I don't have electricity or battery enough, or internet access. I'm using someone else's. I'll try this as soon as I have electricity. Thank you